# How to Find & replace values in a table based on values in another table

Tags: r

I want to find & replace values in DF1$Value with DF1$Value if matches DF1$group=DF2$group

```
DF1
group       Value
12357      ABC D
12575      GHI JK
19718      LMN O
19716      LMN OP
18947      QR S TV

DF2
group       Value
12357      ABCD
12575      GHIJK
19718      LMNO
18947      QR STV
```

How can I write this statement in R?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)

DF1[ DF2, on = c("group"), Value := i.Value]
## here the 'Value' of DF1 is being updated with the 'Value' of DF2
## where there is a common 'group' value between the two tables.    

DF1
   group  Value
1: 12357   ABCD
2: 12575  GHIJK
3: 19718   LMNO
4: 19716 LMN OP
5: 18947 QR STV
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` package, you may need to convert the value columns from factor to character.

```
library(dplyr)
DF1$Value <- as.character(DF1$Value)
DF2$Value <- as.character(DF2$Value)
merge(DF1, DF2, by = "group", all.x = T) %>% 
      mutate(Value = ifelse(!is.na(Value.y), Value.y, Value.x)) %>% 
      select(group, Value)

  group        Value
1 12357         ABCD
2 12575        GHIJK
3 18947       QR STV
4 19716       LMN OP
5 19718         LMNO
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option with `match`

```
 i1 <- with(DF1, match(group, DF2$group))
 DF1$Value <- with(DF1, ifelse(is.na(i1), Value, DF2$Value[i1]))
 DF1
 #  group  Value
 #1 12357   ABCD
 #2 12575  GHIJK
 #3 19718   LMNO
 #4 19716 LMN OP
 #5 18947 QR STV
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution using `merge`:

```
transform(merge(df1,df2, by='group', all.x=TRUE), 
          Value = ifelse(is.na(Value.y), Value.x, Value.y)
)[c('group','Value')]
##   group  Value
## 1 12357   ABCD
## 2 12575  GHIJK
## 3 18947 QR STV
## 4 19716 LMN OP
## 5 19718   LMNO
```

This assumes that you have `character` values in `df1` and `df2`.  Otherwise you need to wrap `Value.x` and `Value.y` with `as.character`:

```
... ifelse(is.na(Value.y), as.character(Value.x), as.character(Value.y)) ...
```